# SFTP server on raspberry pi with multiple users

Tags: debian, raspbian, sftp

I'm trying to make a NAS out of my raspberrypi and instead of using Open Media Vault, I want to see if I can do it with Raspbian since I want to also install nextcloud and installing nextcloud on open media vault looks hard. So the main thing I want to be able to do it run an sftp server on the pi but have the ability to easily add users and give them access to different folders mounted to my pi (external hard drive) as you would easily be able to do on a synology NAS. But I can't find a way to do it without installing something like OMV. Any recommendations of software I can install on the pi that gives me a nice sftp configuration to add users and give users access to certain folders?
Cheers,
Josh

Comment: You really only need any linux install with ssh (all of them), no additional software required.  Easily add users and give access is subjective but are the default linux user management tools not sufficient?

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-an-sftp-server-on-linux/

Comment: Is there no nice gui interface for doing this like open media vault or the synology os? I'd rather not have to do so much cmd action just to add a new user then symlink the folder I want to give it access to into its home directory?

Comment: I don't see why you would need to symlink any folders but you can install a gui on top of most (if not all?) linux distributions.

Comment: Im just not sure how to give a user access to only a certain folder off a hdd? And I'm using raspbian but there are no good gui interfaces for setting up sftp users.

Comment: All you need to do is create a user and give them access to the directory in question.  They will then have sftp access to it.  The GUI should have "easy" tools for user creation and file permission management (the terminal is easier IMO).